# Using str_detect in R to sort a datatable based on a character variable column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a datatable with mainly numerical column variables, as well as one character variable containing ~30 different character variables. I would like to use str_detect in R to read information in the column of data type character,  compare it to a vector containing a set of strings, create a new dt column, and assign a value in this new column based on whether the initial column contained any of the strings found in the character/string vector.

Explaining in words isn't very clear, so I'll try to use iris as an example to explain, although this dataset is a bit too simple; I wouldn't really want to do what I'm attempting here with iris.

This is what I tried:

```
mydesiredgrouping <- c("virginica","versicolor")
test <- iris %>% mutate(Group1 = if_else(str_detect(iris$Species, mydesiredgrouping), "mygroup", "notmygroup"))
```

But when I do this I get the following error.

> Error in `mutate()`: ℹ In argument: `Group1 = if_else(...)`. Caused by
> error in `str_detect()`: ! Can't recycle `string` (size 150) to match
> `pattern` (size 2). Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error
> occurred.

Does anyone know what I need to change?
This is the output I am hoping to get, but am not getting.

[image: Desired Output]

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that in my own dataset I had some partial matches, which was why I was trying to use str_detect in the first place. Fortunately, I got the answer I was looking for despite this, but I am adding this information for clarity.

Comment: Are you using `str_detect()` because you are after partial matches? I.e. should you get the same expected result from iris when using `c("virgi","color")`?

Comment: you probably want to concatentate mydesiredgrouping  with vertical bars  `|` to turn it into a regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ronak's answer is the best if you are sure you have complete matches. If you have partial matches, you can use vertical bars to collapse the search terms into one regex, and then pass that as a pattern to `str_detect`:

```
test <- iris %>% mutate(Group1 = if_else(str_detect(Species, paste(mydesiredgrouping, collapse = "|")), "mygroup", "notmygroup"))
```

Comment: I actually did have partial matches so this was a perfect solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `%in%` instead of pattern matching of `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)

mydesiredgrouping <- c("virginica","versicolor")

test <- iris %>% 
           mutate(Group1 = if_else(Species %in% mydesiredgrouping, 
                                   "mygroup", "notmygroup"))
test

#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species     Group1
#1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa notmygroup
#2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa notmygroup
#3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa notmygroup
#4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa notmygroup
#...
#...
#...
#147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica    mygroup
#148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica    mygroup
#149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica    mygroup
#150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica    mygroup
```